# $u_n \to u \in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ (and equibounded in $W^{1,\infty}$) then $\frac{\partial_{xx} u_n}{n} \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u_n$ equibounded in $W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $\partial_{xx} u_n$ is bounded in $W^{-1,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. We also suppose $u_n \to u \in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Do we have that
$$\frac{u_n}{n} \to 0$$
$$\frac{\partial_x u_n}{n} \to 0$$
$$\frac{\partial_{xx} u_n}{n} \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: All the sequences in the post converge with respect to certain norms and may diverge with respect to other norms. You need to specify the norm/norms, for each sequence. For example $\partial_x u_n/n\to 0$ in the $L^2-$norm, but the sequence might diverge with respect to the $W^1-$norm.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: I was thinking about pointwise convergence, but I'd appreciate if you could explain in an answer what are the types of norm convergences that we have under these hypotheses.

Answer (score 0):

Take $u_n(x) = \sin(n^2 x)/n^2$, $n \ge 1$.  Then $u_n$ and $\partial_x u_n$ are uniformly bounded, but $\partial_{xx} u_n(x) = - n^2 \sin(x^2 x)$ so that $$\frac{\partial_{xx}u_n}{n} \not\to 0.$$